# iMacros set variable as text

Tags: imacros

I tried to download html code of each page at this site with iMacro (mozilla extension)

site: //www.faa.gov/uas/legislative_programs/section_333/333_authorizations/ or other similar

But pagination-buttons have names 1,2,3.. so i set ATTR=TXT:{{!LOOP}} and it returns error. 

How I can do it?

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
    TAB T=1
    URL GOTO=http://www.faa.gov/uas/legislative_programs/section_333/333_authorizations/
    SET !LOOP 2
    TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:{{!LOOP}} //here error, but need 1,2,3..etc
    TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=BODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=HTM
    SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER="D:\\aaa\" FILE=site_{{!LOOP}}.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `POS=1` in your commands:

```
' ...
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:{{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=HTM
' ...
```